# CodeFirst configuration error creation reason?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core

I'm a beginner on EntityFramework Core Code first database generation and I have a problem with relation configuration of two entities :

```
 public class EntityParent
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        //Navigation properties to the EntityChildren which have info of start position.
        [ForeignKey("TransformationEntity")]
        public int? TransformationEntityId { get; set; }
        public virtual EntityChildren TransformationEntity { get; set; }

        //Navigation property : List of childrens
        public virtual ICollection<EntityChildren> Childrens { get; set; }
    }

    public class EntityChildren
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int StartPosition { get; set; }

        //List of EntityParents which have this EntityChildren as the start position
        public virtual ICollection<EntityParent> TransformedParents { get; set; }

        //Relation one-to-one(this same table)
        [ForeignKey("EntityChildrenSource")]
        public int? Cadrage { get; set; }
        public virtual EntityChildren EntityChildrenSource { get; set; }
        public virtual EntityChildren EntityChildrenTarget { get; set; }

        //Navigation property to EntityParent
        [ForeignKey("Parent")]
        public int Parent_FK { get; set; }
        public virtual EntityParent Parent { get; set; }
    }
```

The relations between these entities are : 
EntityParent :

- Has one or many children of type EntityChild (1st relation)
- Has zero or one Transformation of type EntityChild (2nd relation)

The goal is to have in the EntityParent the properties :

- List of childrens.
- The EntityChildren that contains Start position.

And in the EntityChildren the properties :

- List of EntityParent which have this entity as start position
- The EntityParent of this EntityChildren
- The EntityChildrenSource
- The EntityChildrenTarget

BUT when executing the command to generate scripts of the  database I have the error bellow :

System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: **Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property 'EntityChildren.TransformedParents' of type 'ICollection'**. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.PropertyMappingValidationConvention.Apply(InternalModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ImmediateConventionScope.OnModelBuilt(InternalModelBuilder modelBuil
der)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.CreateModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder, IModelValidator v
alidator)

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: **Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property 'EntityChildren.TransformedParents' of type 'ICollection<EntityParent>'**. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.
```

at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.PropertyMappingValidationConvention.Apply(InternalModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ImmediateConventionScope.OnModelBuilt(InternalModelBuilder modelBuil
der)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.CreateModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder, IModelValidator v
alidator)

Any help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In EF Core each [relationship](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships) consists of 0, 1 or 2 *navigation properties*. In most of the cases EF Core can automatically determine the relationships and their associated navigation properties. But sometimes it can't, so it throw exception and is expecting you to explicitly specify that by either data annotations, fluent API or combination of the two.

It this particular case the exception message is telling you that EF Core cannot determine the relationship represented by the `EntityChildren.TransformedParents` collection navigation property. You can resolve it by using `[InverseProperty]` data annotation to pair it with the `ParentEntity.TransformationEntity` reference navigation property:

```
[InverseProperty(nameof(EntityParent.TransformationEntity))]
public virtual ICollection<EntityParent> TransformedParents { get; set; }
```

This should be enough in this particular case.

Fluent API are more flexible though because they allow fully configuring all the aspects of the relationship - principal, dependent, navigation properties, dependent FK property, principal PK property, required/optional, cascade delete behavior etc. The corresponding fluent configuration is like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<EntityParent>()
    .HasOne(p => p.TransformationEntity)
    .WithMany(c => c.TransformedParents)
    .HasForeignKey(p => p.TransformationEntityId) // optional (by convention)
    .IsRequired(false) // optional (by convention)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull) // optional (by convention)
    ;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class EntityChildren
{
     public virtual ICollection<EntityParent> TransformedParents { get; set; }
```

and

```
public class EntityParent
{
     public virtual ICollection<EntityChildren> Childrens { get; set; }
```

create a many-to-many relation which is not supported in EF Core.

An intermediate class is obligatory to resolve this problem

For example, a class intermediate class `ParentChildren`

```
 public class ParentChildren
 {
        public int ParentId { get; set; }
        public EntityParent Parent{ get; set; }

        public int ChildId { get; set; }
        public EntityChild Child{ get; set; }
 }
```

then, use `ICollection<ParentChildren>` in your `EntityParent` and `EntityChild`

**DBContext**

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<EntityParent>()
            .HasKey(x => x.Id);

        modelBuilder.Entity<EntityChild>()
            .HasKey(x => x.Id);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ParentChildren>()
            .HasKey(x => new { x.ParentId , x.ChildId });

        modelBuilder.Entity<ParentChildren>()
            .HasOne(x => x.Parent)
            .WithMany(m => m.Childrens)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.ParentId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ParentChildren>()
            .HasOne(x => x.Child)
            .WithMany(e => e.TransformedParents)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.ChildId);
    }
```

Comment: I forget to indicate that the relations between these entities are :
 EntityParent  :
             - Has one or many children of type EntityChild (1st relation)

             - Has zero or one Transformation of type EntityChild (2nd relation)

This is can be resolved by the solution above ?